# remove "()" "," and " ' " from a function output..Python3

Tags: python-3.x

First off, here's the code. (Still new in function creating)

## Function Testing!!

```
def UserInfo(name, age, birth):
    """Read this by doing UserInfo__doc__"""
    print("Name:",name)
    print("Age:",age)
    print("Birth:",birth)
    return

n_input=input("Name?>> ")
a_input=int(input("Age?>> "))
b_input=input("Birth date?(MM DD YYYY)>> ")

UserInfo(n_input, a_input, b_input)
```

## CodeOutput

```
('name:', 'Jaymz')
('age:', 25)
('birth:', '02 26 1991')
```

The int portion of the code outputs no " ' " (which I knew) but still with "()" and ","...
The string portion outputs all the stuff I don't want surrounding my output...
How would you get rid of that in your code?(I learn by seeing other code first on how people do it)

ps. Brainfart?.... Do I have to do a "format" on the output code? or is format only for numbers?

Comment: You're probably executing your code in Python 2.x, where `print` is a keyword, not a function. The parentheses are interpreted as creating a tuple and this tuple is printed.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, I realized, yeah I'm using Py2... Thanks. Would py3 just not output the code like that? and more neater? or should I just start using the below answer with the {} format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get this output because you're using python 2.x. Python 2 thinks you're printing a `tuple`. Python 3 would issue what you want.

As jojonas suggested, using `from __future__ import print_function` also works for all versions. You're not able to use `print` without parentheses after importing that, which is for the best.

But ...

To treat all cases, use `format` instead (using `{}` to indicate the location of the string to insert):

```
def UserInfo(name, age, birth):
    """Read this by doing UserInfo__doc__"""
    print("Name: {}".format(name))
    print("Age: {}".format(age))
    print("Birth: {}".format(birth))
```

Note: this also works but is not as powerful:

```
print("Name: "+name)   # would need `str` for integer, ex `str(age)`
print("Name: %s" % name)  # old-style formatting
```

Comment: This solution is a bit hacky. Yes, it will work on all versions, but something like `from __future__ import print_function` will achieve the same in a cleaner way.

Comment: you are right about that. but the hack is to rely on the way multi-argument `print` works.

Comment: @jojonas: did not find the duplicate for this question BTW. I thought I had seen it but no luck.